# Выдает ошибку main.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Document.getElementsByClassName is not a function не могу понять в чем проблема

Tags: javascript, html

```
----------------------------------------------JavaScript-------------------------------------------------

"use strict"
//координаты клада вводит пользователь
Document.getElementsByClassName('.count1').innerHTML = 0;
Document.getElementsByClassName('.count2').innerHTML = 0;

let count1 = Document.getElementsByClassName('.count1').innerHTML;
let count2 = Document.getElementsByClassName('.count2').innerHTML;

let treasure_x = parseInt(count1);
let treasure_y = parseInt(count2);

// идея, что сторона это число, для упрощения работы
let compas ={
  "север": 0,
  "восток": 1,
  "юг": 2,
  "запад": 3
};

let my_side = 0;
let my_x = 0;
let my_y = 0;

//счетчик ходов
let count = 0;

function right() {
  if(my_side == 0){
    //Увеличивает count1 на 1
    treasure_x++;
    count1 = count1 + treasure_x;
  } else if(my_side == 1){
    //Увеличивает count2 на 1
    treasure_y++;
    count2 = count2 + treasure_x;
  } else if(my_side == 2){
    //Уменьшает count1 на 1
    treasure_x--;
    count1 = count1 - treasure_x;
  } else{
    //Уменьшает count2 на 1
    treasure_x--;
    count2 = count2 - treasure_x;
  }
}

function left() {
  if(my_side == 0){
    //Уменьшает count2 на 1
    treasure_x--;
    count2 = count2 - treasure_x;
  } else if(my_side == 1){
    //Уменьшает count1 на 1
    treasure_x--;
    count1 = count1 - treasure_x;
  } else if(my_side == 2){
    //Увеличивает count1 на 1
    treasure_x++;
    count1 = count1 + treasure_x;
  } else{
    //Увеличивает count2 на 1
    treasure_y++;
    count2 = count2 + treasure_x;
  }
}

function forward() {
  if(my_side == 0){
    //Увеличивает count2 на 1
    treasure_y++;
    count2 = count2 + treasure_x;
  } else if(my_side == 1){
    //Уменьшает count1 на 1
    treasure_x--;
    count1 = count1 - treasure_x;
  } else if(my_side == 2){
    //Уменьшаеты count2 на 1
    treasure_x--;
    count2 = count2 - treasure_x;
  } else{
    //Увеличивает count1 на 1
    treasure_x++;
    count1 = count1 + treasure_x;
  }
}

function turn() {
  if(my_side == 0){
    my_side = 2;
  } else if(my_side == 1){
    my_side = 3;
  } else if(my_side == 2){
    my_side = 0;
  } else{
    my_side = 1;
  }
}

alert("Вы вышли из цикла");

---------------------------------------------------HTML--------------------------------------------------

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex-large">
    <div class="first_cont">
      <input class="btn" type="button" value="Налево" onClick="left();">
      <input class="btn" type="button" value="Направо" onClick="right();">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="cordinata y_cordinata">
          Y
        </div>
        <div class="poligon">
          <div class="kladman">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="small-container">
          <div class="mini-flex">
            <h2 class="count">x:</h2>
            <p class="count count1">0</p>
          </div>
          <div class="mini-flex">
            <h2 class="count">y:</h2>
            <p class="count count2">0</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h1 class="text">Игра "Ищем клад"</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="second_cont">
      <input class="btn" type="button" value="Вперед" onClick="forward();">
      <input class="btn" type="button" value="Разворот" onClick="turn();">
      <div class="cordinata x_cordinata">
        X
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Document` пишется с маленькой буквы, а не с заглавной. Правильно : `document`

Comment: @ArturasLapinskas откуда вы взяли эту информацию?